# Sticky headers relatively to another sibling container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have wrapper-div with 2 childs: `.content-panel` and `main-content`. My `main-content` container has multiple nestings elements, on the most inner level it has list of items with, each of them has h4 elements inside:

**.wrapper-div:**

.content-panel

.main-content

- section1

  - section 1.1 vse-lb-metadata
  - section 1.2 vse-rvs-carousel

    - section 1.3 li

      - section 1.4 div

        - **section 1.5 h4**
    - section 1.3 li

      - section 1.4 div

        - **section 1.5 h4**

What I need to achieve is to make sticky headers behaviour for all `h4` divs (section 1.5) EXACTLY to the sticky headers in this simple example - http://jsfiddle.net/4tmcLjq3/3/ , using `position:sticky`.

The issue is that my the headers should be sticky relatively to bottom of the `.content-panel` class. I know that the `.content-panel` bottom position is always 250px. however, setting position to my h4 elements sticky and setting top position to 250 doesn't do anything:

```
h4 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 250px;
}
```

As I see from my HTML, it happens because setting top: 250px to `h4` elements makes them move down relatively to their parent container, and not relatively to the window or `.content-panel`

Is there . a way to achieve the following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this something like what you're looking for? (You'll likely have to run the snippet in full screen to see it work.) In this example, `.content-panel` has height `250px` and is gray. The `<h4>` headers are yellow and the content blocks are red. I set their `height: 200px` to get the page to scroll.

Note that you still have to set `top: 250px` for the sticky `<h4>` elements, even though `.main-content` has the same attribute. Knowing the height of `.content-panel` makes this a lot easier.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content-panel {
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.main-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
}
.content-div {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #8b0000;
}
h4 {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-div">
<div class="content-panel">
content panel content
</div>
<div class="main-content">
<ul>
<li>
  <div>
    <h4>Header 1</h4>
    <div class="content-div">Content 1</div>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div>
    <h4>Header 2</h4>
    <div class="content-div">Content 2</div>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```